# can anyone give the java code to encrypt files using paillier

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I want to implement encryption on personal files using paillier encryption. Is it possible to encrypt files using this encryption..

Comment: Why shouldnt it be possible?

Comment: Why specifically do you want to use Paillier?  Is it a requirement that someone be able to add two encrypted files (coming up with a encrypted file containing the sum)?

Comment: i want to encrypt file index to store it in cloud. I want to implement paillier encryption in multi keyword top k file retrieval.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,           it is possible.